# Iterate next row each time a while loop starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, while-loop

I have a csv file with links scraped from a streaming API. I have a script (called 'selenium.py') in a while loop, where selenium webdriver takes a screenshot of every url then saves it in a file. More rows are added to the csv file every minute.

My code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header = 0, usecols= ['url','guid'])
while True: 
   i = 0  
   for i, row in df.iterrows():
       r = driver.get(row['url'])
       driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
       i += 1
       for n in range(2):
           file_name = str(row['guid'])
           fn_1 = "date_stamp{n:0>5}.png".format(n = n)
           date_stamp= str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
           fn_1 = date_stamp
           fn=driver.save_screenshot(file_name+ ' ' + date_stamp + '.png')
           sourcepath='/Users/user/'
           destinationpath = '/Users/user/Screen'
           sourcefiles = os.listdir(sourcepath)
           filename= file_name+ ' ' + date_stamp + '.png'
```

**What I need:**

I run the script in jupyter this way:

`while True:
    %run "Selenium.py"
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))`

I need each time the script runs, the iteration increases with one row.

Any help, please?

Comment: `selenium.py` is not a good name for a script since it shares the name of the module

Comment: okay, but this is an example

Comment: Do you mean you want the screenshot-taking script that runs each 60 seconds take the screenshots of only the URLs in the csv that were added during these 60 seconds, without redoing again the csv records that it processed earlier?

Comment: @ godfryd this can be an option, but the original question is how when the loop starts it reads the file + the additional row added by the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move the reading of the csv into the while loop:

```
df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header = 0, usecols= ['url','guid'])
while True:
```

becomes

```
while True: 
    df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header = 0, usecols= ['url','guid'])
```

Now, you can keep track of the number of rows you've read and use skiprows when reading the csv. i.e.

```
i = 1
while True:
  df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header=0, usecols=['url','guid'], skiprows=lambda x: x in range(1, i))
  for i, row in df.iterrows():
    r = driver.get(row['url'])
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    i += 1
```

*That said, you might be better off not using pandas here, and reading each row line by line, either storing it into a dict or the "seen" guid/urls in a set (so you don't fetch them twice).*

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid: do you mean the code will remain the same except moving `df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header = 0, usecols= ['url','guid'], skiprows=i)` under the while True loop?

Comment: @J.Doe yes, and after the i=0. (I think that's the right way to call it, it might be that you have to do `skiprows=lambda x: x in range(1, i)` and start i=1, I haven't tested)

Comment: you mean like this: `while True:
        df = pd.read_csv('screenshot.csv', header = 0, usecols= ['url','guid'], skiprows=i)
        i = 0
        skiprows=lambda x: x in range(1, i)
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            r = driver.get(row['url'])
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            i +=1`

Answer (score 2):

Bundle whatever you are doing in `Selenium.py` into a function such as:

```
def take_screenshot():
    # your code here
```

Then in jupyter import your file with:

```
import Selenium
```

Then you can call the function with:

```
while True:
    Selenium.take_screenshot()
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Comment: Using %run in a for loop does seem like an anti-pattern. Though that take_screenshot function is likely to at least take the url as a parameter, so you're going to need a loop in there.